# P/E & P/B of stocks purchased by Warren Buffett

Tags: investing, value-investing, price-earnings-ratio, book-value

I am looking for data about Warren Buffett's famous purchases.

For e.g. when Warren Buffett purchased stock of Coke, American Express, Moody's & other of his long term purchases what was the P/E & P/B of these stocks when he purchased them.